# template definition of non-template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm getting a "template definition of non-template" compile error while trying to implement something like this :

```
class BaseFoo
{
    BaseFoo();
    ~BaseFoo();

    virtual void method();
};

template <class A>
class Foo : public BaseFoo
{
 Foo();
    ~Foo();

    virtual void method();
};
```

Is it possible to redefine a method in a template class if it was previously defined in its baseclass which is not a templated class ?

Comment: may be you should post a complete example which has this problem, the code above is fine (ignoring access restrictions) (i.e. yes to your last question)

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but you should make `BaseFoo`'s destructor `virtual`.

Comment: You need to put more source code. Present code doesn't generate any error.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this is a bug that was finally fixed in gcc 4.2. See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=27211 .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this sort of thing is perfectly legal. The code you provided compiles fine in gcc 4.2.1.

Is this the exact code you are getting the error for? What compiler are you using?